# Use SVG <param> tag in Angular2

Tags: angular, svg

Have a template:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <g id="tpl1">
                <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                       [attr.xlink:href]="param(url)"
                       [attr.x]="-18" [attr.y]="-30"></image>
            </g>
        </defs>
        <svg:use [attr.x]="25" [attr.y]="25"
                 [attr.xlink:href]="fullPath()+'#tpl1'">
               <param name="url" value="/img.png" />
        </svg:use>
 </svg>
```

getting error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: ':svg:param' is
>   not a known element: ...

fullPath() - 's a function that retrieves active url using LocationStrategy service, it allowed me to use <use>, but now I'm stucked with  param...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, solved, actually it's consist of 2 parts:

1) - error in Angular2.
setting CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA was not helpfull, at least error still appeared, but replacing it with the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA allowed it to pass.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [/***/],
  declarations: [/***/],
  exports: [/***/],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

2) Unfortunately <param> can't be used in SVG, at least in the way I thought of. I was deluded by the [Proposals for the SVG2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/) . So SVG in my version will not work, but I was able to use workaraund, using CSS vars:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <g id="tpl1">
                <circle xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                       [attr.style]="_sanatizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('r:var(--radius)')"
                       [attr.cx]="-18" [attr.cy]="-30"></circle>
            </g>
        </defs>
        <svg:use [attr.x]="25" [attr.y]="25"
                 [attr.xlink:href]="fullPath()+'#tpl1'"
                 [attr.style]="_sanatizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('--radius:10')"
         ></svg:use>
 </svg>
```

As you can see it also required to use DomSanatizer, to set styles.

But bad luck for me again again, xlink:href can't be set in CSS ))), yet I'll leave this post, maybe it will be helpful for someone.

UPD:
for my particular case I end up creating new component instead of using <def>